# Linear programming counter variable

Tags: constraints, counter, linear-programming

I have a binary variable X_i and an integer variable Y_i

I want to use Y as a counter in such a way that Y_i is reset to 0 every time X_i = 1

Is it possible to find constraints that would allow me to do it ?

Here is an example :

X : 001011001

Y : 120100120

edit :

Here are the constraints I find, using a linearization of

```
y(i) = (y(i-1)+1)*(1-x(i))
```

:

```
y[1] == (1-x[1])
    for i in 2:N
        y[i] <= 10000*(1-x[i])
        y[i] <= y[i-1] + 1
        y[i] >= y[i-1] + 1 - 10000*x[i]
```

And here are some results I get

```
x : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
y : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,3,0,1,0,0,0,-9999
```

or

```
x : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1
y : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,-9999,-19998,-29997,-39996,-49995,-49994,-59993,-69992
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: A LP/MIP is a *static* problem. If you want something *dynamic* you have to discretize your time. That means here: you will have one X-var and one Y-var for each time tick. Then it's just a problem of formulating boolean logic (implication + or).

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I have (ILP), I thought it was called the same, my mistake.

So from there, any tips on how I can formulate the problem ?

Comment: I already did. Look up indicator-constraints or logical-constraints in MIP for common formulations and try something. And start by creating propositional-logic which solves this task, then think about linearization of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can express this as:

```
 y(i) = (y(i-1)+1)*(1-x(i))
```

This can be linearized ([link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/05/multiplication-of-continuous-and-binary.html)) or handled by indicator constraints.

Comment: Here are the constraints I find, using your method

    y[1] == (1-x[1])
        for i in 2:N
            y[i] <= 10000*(1-x[i])
            y[i] <= y[i-1] + 1
            y[i] >= y[i,j-1] + 1 - 10000*x[i]

Here is the result I get
x : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
y : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,3,0,1,0,0,0,-9999

What am I doing wrong ?
(edit : how do I write code and carriage return when replying here ? The formatting is awful)

Comment: Check your code: `y[i] >= y[i,j-1] + 1 - 10000*x[i]`. `y[i,j-1]` looks strange. Also add `y[i]>=0`.

Comment: It's because in my project I use multiple rows, don't mind the j, it should have been y[i-1]

Comment: It works perfectly with the y[i] >= 0 condition ! Thanks ! I also witnessed the issue that is mentionned when M is too high. Awesome. What I'm kind of wondering now is : isn't this notation too heavy ? Is there a way to decrease the number of conditions or is this something I'm forced to deal with ?

Comment: As said earlier, you can use indicator constraints.